# calculate the circulation of a vector field around line of intersection of 2 shapes in 3D space

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors

How to calculate the circulation of $\vec{F}=(xyz, -x^2y,xz) $ around the line of intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and the plane $ x+y+z=2\sqrt{2}$? My approach was to parametrize the equation of the cylinder
$x=2\cos(t), y=2\sin(t), z=v$ and then substitute the value of $z$ from the equation of the plan in terms of $x$ and $y$ now that I have the parametric equation of the line of intersection in terms of the parameter $t$, I will write the integral with respect to t (by evaluating the values of $dx$, $dy$, $dz$ in terms of $dt$) now I am stuck at finding the limits of the integration I think it would be from $0$ to $2\pi$ but I am  not sure
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ummm... what's $\vec{F}$?

Comment: Just edited the question and added the value of the vector field

Comment: A little extra help: $\vec{F}$ is a vector field; that means $\vec{F}: \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3, (x,y,z)\mapsto  (xyz, -x^2y,xz)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is completely right and you are nearly there. Using the $x, y ,z$ you have laid out, we have

$$\vec{r}(t) = \langle 2\cos(t), 2\sin(t), 2\sqrt{2} - 2\sin(t) - 2\cos(t) \rangle.$$

You are also right that because it is a cylinder, the bounds are $t = 0$ to $t = 2\pi$. In fact, you can tell this is the case, since your curve is a closed shape (an ellipse):

[image: graph of cylinder intersecting plane]

The key observation from calculus (assuming Uni Calc 3) is that you want the integral in the *direction of the curve*, which is represented by $\vec{r}'(t)$. Thus, to apply a vector field in a particular direction, we use a dot product. And so, you want to find the line integral along the path
$$\oint_C \vec{F}(x,y,z) \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \vec{F}(x(t), y(t), z(t)) \cdot \vec{r}'(t) \; dt.$$

So simple steps from here

1. plug in your parametric equations into $\vec{F}$,
2. find $\vec{r}'$,
3. take the dot product, and
4. take the integral.